# Помогите с решением проблемы на Ардуино

Tags: arduino

Arduino: 1.8.11 (Windows 10), Плата:"Arduino Uno"

> C:\Users\USER\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Tone\Tone.cpp:26:10: fatal
>   error: wiring.h: No such file or directory

```
#include <wiring.h>

      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Ошибка компиляции для платы Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачать новую версию библиотеки, либо вручную переименуйте:

```
#include <wiring_private.h>
```